# For a given point, determine if it is on an arc segment

Tags: c#, .net, geometry

Looked a few times for this and couldn't find it, so hopefully someone can help me out.

I have an arc segment, defined by startPoint, endPoint, and center.

I have a point, p, that I want to know if it resides on the arc segment.

I've seen a few solutions for if it's within the arc pie, but not on the segment itself.

```
public static bool PointIsOnArcSegment(PointF p, PointF startPoint, PointF endPoint, PointF center)
{
   ???
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sweep angle is also known. (clockwise or counter-clockwise)

Comment: If you're looking for the formula, that sounds more like a math question than a programming question.

Comment: That would be why i tagged "geometry" in this as well.  Although a method/library/etc that I can use in C# would be just as helpful.  Your comment was not helpful.

Comment: Note that once you have the formula you might want to use tolerances since exact values cannot be represented by floats.

Comment: I meant this might be the wrong place to ask - a math forum might be better. But if you're able to determine if it falls within the "pie", then I imagine you could just check that the distance from center is the same as the distance of `startPoint` or `endPoint` from the center to determine if it's on the arc.

Comment: See? that was much more helpful.

Comment: You deleted your other question before I could post this: "You've provided three disjoint lines of code. An MCVE is something that someone can copy and paste to reproduce on their own machine. Your example is neither minimal, complete, or verifiable. One added benefit of an MCVE is that, many times, while trying to produce it, the original problem is discovered. Go create a new project and create a minimal example that mimics the bevahior you're seeing in your real application."

Answer (score 0):

Rather than representing your arc as three points you should represent it as a single point (the center), a starting angle (e.g. 30 degrees), an ending angle (e.g. 45 degrees), and a radius.

Then to test if a point is on your arc you can just figure out the distance and angle of your point from the center and compare it with the radius and starting/ending angles (using a threshold).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the points to polar coordinates around the center of the circle.

First check if the test point is on the whole circle by comparing the radii. Chances are high that you need a tolerance on equality (the absolute difference of the radii gives you the distance of the point to the circle).

If the first test passes, check the angles. Here the discussion is a little complicated because you need to determine which angle interval defines your arc, and deal with the "phase wrapping", i.e. the period of 2π radians.

Extra hint: to determine the angles, use the atan2 function, which works on a full turn.